# Azure custom 404 page

Tags: html, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have created a web application using Microsoft Azure and uploaded static html pages to the web application.

It works fine, however, I would like to set a custom 404 page. Where or how can I do this using the Azure portal ?

Just to be clear, this is not a visual studio project, it's just some static html files. I just want to tell azure to use my 404 page instead of the default text it displays when a page cannot be found.

**EDIT**

Please note, this has nothing to do with IIS. I dont even have a web.config file. I am simply hosting some static html files in Azure and want a custom 404 page. I have already made the 404.html page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable custom errors in Azure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059009/enable-custom-errors-in-azure)

Comment: I dont think so @J.Titus . This has nothing to do with IIS. I dont even have a web.config . I am just using plain Azure for hosting files. see it as a testing environment for my static files.

Comment: When you say uploaded...to the web application, do you mean Azure Web App?

Comment: @AbhaySaraf yes, but it seems I got it sorted for now.

Comment: Great. Just to clarify Azure Web Apps/ Azure Cloud services are still using an IIS server in the backend to serve the request and hence web.config is still the mechanism to achieve any configuration.

Comment: @AbhaySaraf thanks for that valuable info

Comment: The solution is most unfortunate - now if I'm deploying a zipped static site I need to include web.config in my lovely virginal javascript app or else have a non source controlled file lying around in kudu

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Seems like you have to add a web.config file in your root directory. This seems like a workaround, but doing that and adding the following code works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
            <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <error statusCode="404" path="/404.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I added my web.config in the folder under `wwwroot` followed this a bit (i added `<clear />` `500`, `401`, etc.) and it worked like a charm

Comment: I just used IIS manager to create code similar to the above. It left out the attributes on httpErrors but still works nicely.

Comment: Thanks, Janpan :)

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but you refer to 404.ASP - This does not really exist - So where to put the HTML code for the 404 page?

Answer (score 4):

Follow these steps to configure a custom 404 page for a Azure Static Web App:

- Create a file named ***staticwebapp.config.json*** in root page (same folder as starting page i.e. index.html)
- put these lines inside it:

  ```
   {       
      "responseOverrides": {
        "404": {
          "rewrite": "/404.html"
        }
      }
   }
  ```
- Put your custom 404 page in root or subfolder (in this example 404.html is  in root folder)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of testing and research, it was found that using responseMode="ExecuteURL" would result in a correct redirect, but the browser would report 200 Status rather than a 404. To fix this we removed the "**/**" and changed to **responseMode="File"** based on insight from this post: [web.config errors fail with responseMode="File"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17533579/)

We are just hosting a simple static HTML site, not a web app, and this code worked:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <system.web>
            <customErrors defaultRedirect="404.html" mode="RemoteOnly">
                <error statusCode="404" redirect="404.html" />
                <error statusCode="500" redirect="500.html" />
            </customErrors>
        </system.web>
        <system.webServer>
            <httpErrors existingResponse="Replace" defaultResponseMode="File" errorMode="Custom">
                <remove statusCode="404" />
                <error statusCode="404" path="404.html" responseMode="File" />
                <remove statusCode="500" />
                <error statusCode="500" path="500.html" responseMode="File" />
            </httpErrors>
        </system.webServer>      
    </configuration>
```