# Error Pages Are Not Being Routed To From Web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, custom-error-pages

I finally was able to make the 404 and 500 errors redirect but when they do, they give me one of two results.

When I use this (specifically for 404s):

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="404"/>
  <remove statusCode="500"/>
  <error statusCode="404" path="/Home/PageNotFound" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  <error statusCode="500" path="/Home/InternalServerError" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

And type in a non existing link (e.g., localhost:11111/yo), I  get a white page with nothing on it.

And when I use this (specifically for 404s):

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="404"/>
  <remove statusCode="500"/>
  <error statusCode="404" path="/Home/PageNotFound" responseMode="File" />
  <error statusCode="500" path="/Home/InternalServerError" responseMode="File" />
</httpErrors>
```

And type in a non existing link (e.g., localhost:11111/yo), I get this line of text on a white page:

*The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.*

I put breakpoints inside of both of my error pages and they didn't hit in both examples

Here are my error pages:

```
public ActionResult PageNotFound()
{
    Response.StatusCode = 404;
    return View();
}
public ActionResult InternalServerError()
{
    Response.StatusCode = 500;
    return View();
}
```

They are inside of HomeController, hence `path="/Home/...`

How do I make it so that they hit when an error has occurred (I assume the solution for a 404 would be the same for a 500). I put a paragraph in my 404 and 500 page that says "Hi." That's how I know it will work.

I, also, tried this solution with the slashes, and it didn't work [web.config errors fail with responseMode="File"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533579/web-config-errors-fail-with-responsemode-file)

Answer (score 0):

> Web.config Setting

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
      <error redirect="~/Error/NotFound" statusCode="404" />
    </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

> ErrorController

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
    public ViewResult NotFound()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;  //you may want to set this to 200
        return View("NotFound");
    }
}
```

> Error.cshtml Page

```
 @model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo
@{
    Layout = "_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Error";
}
<div class="list-header clearfix">
    <span>Error</span>
</div>
<div class="list-sfs-holder">
    <div class="alert alert-error">
        An unexpected error has occurred. Please contact the system administrator.
    </div>
    @if (Model != null && HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled)
    {
        <div>
            <p>
                <b>Exception:</b> @Model.Exception.Message<br />
                <b>Controller:</b> @Model.ControllerName<br />
                <b>Action:</b> @Model.ActionName
            </p>
            <div style="overflow:scroll">
                <pre>
                    @Model.Exception.StackTrace
                </pre>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: @BradleyWilliamElko no, you can have another controller name

Comment: @BradleyWilliamElko do this setting after hosting in IIS

Comment: @BradleyWilliamElko in will not work in the Visual Studio, if you host on IIS server then it will work.